# if statements don't working good

Tags: php

I've some problems with my statements. The intention is that they check if the user exists, that the user is staff (can not be banned) and that the user is probably already banned. I don't know what I doing wrong. With 3 statements, I can build if more then I can't. There's only a problem with the statements, the query's are good. I've tested and when I try to ban myself, it's possible, when I had 3 statements, it was not.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$bantype = $input->FilterText($_POST['bantype']);
$value = $input->FilterText($_POST['value']);
$reason = $input->FilterText($_POST['reason']);
$length = $_POST['length'] ? $input->EscapeString((time()+$_POST['length'])) : '';

$user_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$value."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
$user_sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bans WHERE value = '".$value."' LIMIT 1") or       die(mysql_error());
$user_exists = mysql_num_rows($user_sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($user_sql) == 0) {
echo 'This user does not exist and can not be banned.';
} while($fox = mysql_fetch_array($user_sql)) 

if ($fox['rank'] > 3) 
echo 'This user is marked as staff can not be banned.';

if (mysql_num_rows($user_sql2) > 0) {
echo 'This user is already banned.';

} else 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO bans (bantype, value, reason, expire, added_by,
added_date,appeal_state) VALUES 
('$bantype','$value','$reason','$length',
'".$user->row['username']."','" . date('d/m/Y H:i') . "','0')");
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: The queries are **not** good.  You're **wide open** to SQL injection attacks and you will be hacked if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.  Also, can you be more consistent in your bracketing and indentation?  It's not entirely clear for me what you're trying to do and what the problem is.  You should narrow your question down.  If you have a problem with `if` statements, then what's all the SQL doing in there?  Break it down to `true` and `false` values and lets look at it.

Comment: `while($fox = mysql_fetch_array($user_sql))` combined with that indentation... hm...

Comment: This is what's happening when the button is submitted (POST). I'm using Input FilterText for the postdata so I think it's safe or not? I've added the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to put this in a comment but I think your error is from missing brackets, these { } brackets. Did you copy your code over right to stack overflow?

```
// This should be your while loop
while($fox = mysql_fetch_array($user_sql)) { //Do stuff here }

// Same issue here
if ($fox['rank'] > 3) { //Do stuff here }
```

Missing brackets will break the code, even is you do not intend to do anything after the check. So other pointers and also possible issues with your code:

> Your missing a closing bracket after the else statement
>   Your else statement seems to be used wrong. You have it attached to the last IF statement you ran, if will ignore all the other checks that you except that last one.

New code should be something like this:

```
 $msg = ''; // Set up variable to carry reply
 if (mysql_num_rows($user_sql) == 0) {
    $msg .= 'This user does not exist and can not be banned.'; // Add to msg
 } 
 while($fox = mysql_fetch_array($user_sql)){ // Do something here
 // I think you meant for this to surround your next statements?
 if ($fox['rank'] > 3) {
     $msg .= 'This user is marked as staff can not be banned.'; // Add to msg
 } // Close IF
 if (mysql_num_rows($user_sql2) > 0) {
     $msg .= 'This user is already banned.'; // Add to msg

 } // Close IF
 } // Close While

 // Change else to a new IF
 if ($msg=='') { // You could also do if($msg!=false) in this case
    // YOUR MYSQL QUERY HERE
 } else {
    // Use $msg for something. I usually apply it to a cookie
    // Send the user back and then display the result
 }
```

ALSO as others have said there are validation errors to look at. You should protect against SQL attacks and so on.

Comment: I thought it was safe because I use filter text and you must first submit with POST.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by filter text but you should always run checks or sanitation SERVER side and not just client side. Client side is more for convenience because everyone hates filling out forms only to find out they did stuff wrong. Glad I could help though.